# Remove duplicates from a nested list

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have a list

```
A = [['1'],['1','2'],['1','2','3','1','2'],['3','3','3']]
```

and I want to make my list to

```
A = [['1'],['1','2'],['1','2','3'],['3']]
```

ie I want to remove duplicate elements within the elements in a list ..

Comment: If order doesn't matter just convert to `set` and back to `list`: `[list(set(x)) for x in A]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing duplicates in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One-liner (If order doesn't matter) :

```
A = [['1'],['1','2'],['1','2','3','1','2'],['3','3','3']]
A = [list(set(a)) for a in A]
print(A) # => [['1'], ['2', '1'], ['3', '2', '1'], ['3']]
```

One-liner (If order matters) :

```
A = [['1'],['1','2'],['1','2','3','1','2'],['3','3','3']]
A = [sorted(set(a), key=a.index) for a in A]
print(A) # => [['1'], ['1', '2'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['3']]
```

Answer (score 1):

A functional version, with `functools`:

```
>>> import functools
>>> A = [['1'],['1','2'],['1','2','3','1','2'],['3','3','3']]
>>> print ([functools.reduce(lambda result,x:result if x in result else result+[x], xs, []) for xs in A])
[['1'], ['1', '2'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['3']]
```

The lambda function adds an element to the `result` list only if that element is not present in the list. Not very efficient, but keeps the order of elements.

Also note that with Python 2, you don't need to import `functools`: `reduce` is a builtin function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generator:

```
def remove_dups(l):
   for a in l:
      new_l = []
      for b in a:
          if b not in new_l:
             new_l.append(b)
      yield new_l

A = [['1'],['1','2'],['1','2','3','1','2'],['3','3','3']]
print(list(remove_dups(A)))
```

Output:

```
[['1'], ['1', '2'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['3']]
```